# 100% width in React Native Flexbox

Tags: flexbox, react-native

I have already read several flexbox tutorial, but I still cannot make this simple task to work.

How can I make the red box to 100% width?

[image]

Code:

```
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Text style={styles.welcome}>
      Welcome to React Natives
    </Text>
    <Text style={styles.line1}>
      line1
    </Text>
    <Text style={styles.instructions}>
      Press Cmd+R to reload,{'\n'}
      Cmd+D or shake for dev menu
    </Text>
  </View>
```

style:

```
container: {
  flex: 1,
  justifyContent: 'center',
  alignItems: 'center',
  backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  borderWidth: 1,
  flexDirection: 'column',
},
welcome: {
  fontSize: 20,
  textAlign: 'center',
  margin: 10,
  borderWidth: 1,
},
line1: {
    backgroundColor: '#FDD7E4',
},
instructions: {
  textAlign: 'center',
  color: '#333333',
  marginBottom: 5,
  borderWidth: 1,
},
```

Thank you!

**Update 1:**
Suggestion by Nishanth Shankar, adding
`flex:1` for the wrapper,
`flexDirection: 'row'`

Output:

[image]

Code:

```
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <View style={{flex:1}}>
      <Text style={styles.welcome}>
        Welcome to React Natives
      </Text>
    </View>
    <View style={{flex:1}}>
      <Text style={styles.line1}>
        line1
      </Text>
    </View>
    <View style={{flex:1}}>
      <Text style={styles.instructions}>
        Press Cmd+R to reload,{'\n'}
        Cmd+D or shake for dev menu
      </Text>
    </View>
  </View>

  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
    borderWidth: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
    borderWidth: 1,
  },
  line1: {
      backgroundColor: '#FDD7E4',
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
    borderWidth: 1,
  },
```

Answer (score 532, accepted):

Simply add `alignSelf: "stretch"` to your item's stylesheet.

```js
line1: {
    backgroundColor: '#FDD7E4',
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    textAlign: 'center',
},
```

Comment: Using alignSelf stretch, I had an issue with Android - I had an Image with 'absolute' position and in this case, even using 'stretch', such box gets padded to the edge of the elements contained within. Dimensions.get('window').width worked both on iOS and Android in my case.

Comment: This one way solved all of my 'full width' problems, check it out: https://snack.expo.io/S1PWQqkcZ

Comment: It seems like `width: "100%"` should also work but it doesn't.  I think I don't understand when `alignSelf: "stretch"` works vs  `width: "100%"`.  @Corentin any ideas?  Thx!

Comment: @st_bk was a life saver there! However, I found a better solution for the event that you're absolutely positioning and need to stretch: `position: absolute, top: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0, right: 0`

Comment: to @lance.dolan point - you really only need the left and right params if you are looking for width 100%. Also i am not 100% on this, but for the alignStretch rule to work you have to have set flexDirection:  'row', because it is set as column by default.

Comment: @virtualLast I think flex-direction is set to `row` by default as opposed to `column` as stated above. Correct me if I'm wrong

Answer (score 149):

You should use [Dimensions](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/dimensions.html#content)

First, define Dimensions.

```js
import { Dimensions } from "react-native";

var width = Dimensions.get('window').width; //full width
var height = Dimensions.get('window').height; //full height
```

then, change `line1` style like below:

```js
line1: {
    backgroundColor: '#FDD7E4',
    width: width,
},
```

Comment: thx Melih Mucuk!  alignSelf: "stretch" suggested by Corentin S. is the easiest and simple so I accepted that answer.

However, having Dimensions leads me to a new way to play around the layout.  In some cases, we could adjust the items programmatically, thank you!

Comment: @Melih I find the width returned is wrong on my Android device. The right width should be 720px, but 360px returns.

Comment: @peacepassion, you got 360, because your device dpi is scaled 2x. Try `Dimensions.get('window').scale` - this should return 2 in your case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am dealing with a container with a background and your suggestion fits perfectly.

Comment: good answer, this seems more legit vs the stretch but i guess it depends

Comment: This will not work when the device is rotated. It's better to use adaptive layout.

Comment: `dimensions` is not part of react. It should be imported from *react-native*

Comment: ...I tried this, but it just seems so hacky (and probably ill-performant). I feel like they want you to use the flexbox properties

Comment: @laynemoseley this can easily be addressed by adding 'change' listener to dimensions, on rotation you can just update the width and height

Answer (score 32):

**Editted:**

In order to flex only the center text, a different approach can be taken - **Unflex the other views.**

- Let flexDirection remain at 'column'
- remove the `alignItems : 'center'` from container
- add `alignSelf:'center'` to the textviews that you don't want to flex

You can wrap the Text component in a View component and give the View a flex of 1.

The flex will give :

100% width if the `flexDirection:'row'` in styles.container

100% height if the `flexDirection:'column'` in styles.container

Comment: yes, I tried to set flexDirection:'row' and flex: 1 so that the width go to 100%.

However, the components are all inline and cannot go to the next line.
even I used flexWrap: 'wrap'

Comment: any luck with the new method franfran?

Comment: the alignSelf: 'stretch' suggested by Corentin S. works.

Answer (score 18):

**Here you go:**

Just change the line1 style as per below:

```
line1: {
    backgroundColor: '#FDD7E4',
    width:'100%',
    alignSelf:'center'
}
```

Comment: I am very happy this worked! I don't know why, I assumed percentage values weren't working in RN....

Answer (score 6):

Use javascript to get the width and height and add them in View's style.
To get full width and height, use `Dimensions.get('window').width`
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/dimensions.html

```js
getSize() {
    return {
        width: Dimensions.get('window').width, 
        height: Dimensions.get('window').height
    }
}
```

and then,

```js
<View style={[styles.overlay, this.getSize()]}>
```

Comment: Ooh, I like this. Possibly not the best solution but it did solve my problem. Not to mention that it's a pretty neat function in general.

Answer (score 6):

First add Dimension component:

```js
import { AppRegistry, Text, View,Dimensions } from 'react-native';
```

Second define Variables:

```js
var height = Dimensions.get('window').height;
var width = Dimensions.get('window').width;
```

Third put it in your stylesheet:

```js
textOutputView: {
    flexDirection:'row',
    paddingTop:20,
    borderWidth:1,
    borderColor:'red',
    height:height*0.25,
    backgroundColor:'darkgrey',
    justifyContent:'flex-end'
}
```

Actually in this example I wanted to make responsive view and wanted to view only 0.25 of the screen view so I multiplied it with 0.25, if you wanted 100% of the screen don't multiply it with any thing like this:

```js
textOutputView: {
    flexDirection:'row',
    paddingTop:20,
    borderWidth:1,
    borderColor:'red',
    height:height,
    backgroundColor:'darkgrey',
    justifyContent:'flex-end'
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`width: '100%'` and `alignSelf: 'stretch'` didn't work for me. `Dimensions` didn't suite my task cause I needed to operate on a deeply nested view. Here's what worked for me, if I rewrite your code. I just added some more `View`s and used `flex` properties to achieve the needed layout:

```js
  {/* a column */}
  <View style={styles.container}>
    {/* some rows here */}
    <Text style={styles.welcome}>
      Welcome to React Natives
    </Text>
    {/* this row should take all available width */}
    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
      {/* flex 1 makes the view take all available width */}
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Text style={styles.line1}>
          line1
        </Text>
      </View>
      {/* I also had a button here, to the right of the text */}
    </View>
    {/* the rest of the rows */}
    <Text style={styles.instructions}>
      Press Cmd+R to reload,{'\n'}
      Cmd+D or shake for dev menu
    </Text>
  </View>
```

Answer (score 3):

just remove the `alignItems: 'center'` in the container styles and add `textAlign: "center"` to the `line1` style like given below.

It will work well

```
container: {
  flex: 1,
  justifyContent: 'center',
  backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  borderWidth: 1,
}

line1: {
    backgroundColor: '#FDD7E4',
    textAlign:'center'
},
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Style ={{width : "100%"}}
```

**try this:**

```css
StyleSheet generated: {
  "width": "80%",
  "textAlign": "center",
  "marginTop": 21.8625,
  "fontWeight": "bold",
  "fontSize": 16,
  "color": "rgb(24, 24, 24)",
  "fontFamily": "Trajan Pro",
  "textShadowColor": "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)",
  "textShadowOffset": {
    "width": 0,
    "height": 0.5
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a proper answer to the question. Do not provide a link without first explaining here what it is about.

Answer (score 2):

> Noted: Try to fully understanding about flex concept.

```js
       <View style={{
          flex: 2,
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center'
        }}>
          <View style ={{
              flex: 1,
              alignItems: 'center, 
              height: 50, 
              borderWidth: 1, 
              borderColor: '#000' 
          }}>
               <Text>Welcome to React Nativ</Text>
           </View>
           <View style={{
              flex: 1,
              alignItems: 'center,
              borderWidth: 1, 
              borderColor: 'red ', 
              height: 50
            }}
            >
              <Text> line 1 </Text>
            </View>
          <View style={{
            flex: 1,
            alignItems: 'center, 
            height: 50, 
            borderWidth: 1,                     
            borderColor: '#000'
          }}>
             <Text>
              Press Cmd+R to reload,{'\n'}
              Cmd+D or shake for dev menu
             </Text>
           </View>
       </View>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use width:'100%'

```
line1: {
      backgroundColor: '#FDD7E4',
width: '100%'
  },
```