# Flexbox View does not wrap Image in React Native

Tags: react-native, flexbox

When I have an Image inside a View with 'flex: 1' the View does not wrap the Image.

When I paste my code into [react-native-web-player](https://dabbott.github.io/react-native-web-player/#code=%2F**%0A%20*%20Sample%20React%20Native%20App%0A%20*%20https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Ffacebook%2Freact-native%0A%20*%20%40flow%0A%20*%2F%0A%0Aimport%20*%20as%20React%20from%20'react'%3B%0Aimport%20%7B%20AppRegistry%2C%20View%2C%20Image%2C%20Text%2C%20StyleSheet%20%7D%20from%20'react-native'%3B%0A%0Aimport%20SplitView%20from%20'.%2Fcomponents%2FSplitView'%3B%0A%0Afunction%20PurchaseLine()%20%7B%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20tslint%3Adisable-next-line%3Amax-line-length%0A%20%20const%20imgUrl%20%3D%0A%20%20%20%20'https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.shopify.com%2Fs%2Ffiles%2F1%2F0938%2F8938%2Fproducts%2F10231100205_1_1315x1800_300_CMYK_1024x1024.jpeg%3Fv%3D1445623369'%3B%0A%20%20return%20(%0A%20%20%20%20%3CView%20style%3D%7Bstyles.container%7D%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CImage%20source%3D%7B%7B%20uri%3A%20imgUrl%20%7D%7D%20style%3D%7Bstyles.img%7D%20%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2FView%3E%0A%20%20)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20styles%20%3D%20StyleSheet.create(%7B%0A%20%20container%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20flex%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20%20%20backgroundColor%3A%20'red'%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20img%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20width%3A%2045%2C%0A%20%20%20%20height%3A%2062%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D)%3B%0A%0Aexport%20default%20class%20Datakasse%20extends%20React.Component%3Cobject%2C%20object%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20render()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20(%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CView%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CPurchaseLine%20%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FView%3E%0A%20%20%20%20)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0AAppRegistry.registerComponent('Datakasse'%2C%20()%20%3D%3E%20Datakasse)%3B%0A) it works as expected..

The right image is what I expected, while the left is the actual result:

[image: screenshot of simulator and web player]

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, View, Image, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

import SplitView from './components/SplitView';

function PurchaseLine() {
  // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
  const imgUrl =
    'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0938/8938/products/10231100205_1_1315x1800_300_CMYK_1024x1024.jpeg?v=1445623369';
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Image source={{ uri: imgUrl }} style={styles.img} />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'red'
  },
  img: {
    width: 45,
    height: 62
  }
});

export default class Datakasse extends React.Component<object, object> {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <PurchaseLine />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Datakasse', () => Datakasse);
```

**UPDATE:**

"height: 100%" or "flex: 1" on the outermost container, and not setting "flex: 1" on PurchaseLine's container seems to work.. Confused why I can't set the latter tho..

[image]

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, View, Image, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

import SplitView from './components/SplitView';

function PurchaseLine() {
  // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
  const imgUrl =
    'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0938/8938/products/10231100205_1_1315x1800_300_CMYK_1024x1024.jpeg?v=1445623369';
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Image source={{ uri: imgUrl }} style={styles.img} />
      <Text>1 x Jacket</Text>
      <Text>$99.99</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    alignItems: 'center',
    padding: 10
  },
  img: {
    width: 45,
    height: 62
  }
});

export default class Datakasse extends React.Component<object, object> {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ height: '100%', backgroundColor: 'blue' }}>
        <PurchaseLine />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Datakasse', () => Datakasse);
```

Comment: there is a small hack on react-native with setting the width: null, that is going to stretch it to 100%, have you tried that? Based on your example this works as expected

Comment: I think changing `flexDirection` of container might help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33312563/205477

Comment: flexDirection does not help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of a react-native "hack" and **define the width as null** like { width: null }. This will make it stretch at 100%. See also the example [here](https://dabbott.github.io/react-native-web-player/#code=%2F**%0A%20*%20Sample%20React%20Native%20App%0A%20*%20https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Ffacebook%2Freact-native%0A%20*%20%40flow%0A%20*%2F%0A%0Aimport%20*%20as%20React%20from%20'react'%3B%0Aimport%20%7B%20AppRegistry%2C%20View%2C%20Image%2C%20Text%2C%20StyleSheet%20%7D%20from%20'react-native'%3B%0A%0Aimport%20SplitView%20from%20'.%2Fcomponents%2FSplitView'%3B%0A%0Afunction%20PurchaseLine()%20%7B%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20tslint%3Adisable-next-line%3Amax-line-length%0A%20%20const%20imgUrl%20%3D%0A%20%20%20%20'https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.shopify.com%2Fs%2Ffiles%2F1%2F0938%2F8938%2Fproducts%2F10231100205_1_1315x1800_300_CMYK_1024x1024.jpeg%3Fv%3D1445623369'%3B%0A%20%20return%20(%0A%20%20%20%20%3CView%20style%3D%7Bstyles.container%7D%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CImage%20source%3D%7B%7B%20uri%3A%20imgUrl%20%7D%7D%20style%3D%7Bstyles.img%7D%20%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2FView%3E%0A%20%20)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20styles%20%3D%20StyleSheet.create(%7B%0A%20%20container%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20flex%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20%20%20backgroundColor%3A%20'red'%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20img%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20width%3A%20null%2C%0A%20%20%20%20height%3A%2062%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D)%3B%0A%0Aexport%20default%20class%20Datakasse%20extends%20React.Component%3Cobject%2C%20object%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20render()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20(%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CView%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CPurchaseLine%20%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FView%3E%0A%20%20%20%20)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0AAppRegistry.registerComponent('Datakasse'%2C%20()%20%3D%3E%20Datakasse)%3B%0A) based on your code

UPDATE:

the alignSelf what you are looking for. Sample [here](https://dabbott.github.io/react-native-web-player/#code=%2F**%0A%20*%20Sample%20React%20Native%20App%0A%20*%20https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Ffacebook%2Freact-native%0A%20*%20%40flow%0A%20*%2F%0A%0Aimport%20*%20as%20React%20from%20'react'%3B%0Aimport%20%7B%20AppRegistry%2C%20View%2C%20Image%2C%20Text%2C%20StyleSheet%20%7D%20from%20'react-native'%3B%0A%0Aimport%20SplitView%20from%20'.%2Fcomponents%2FSplitView'%3B%0A%0Afunction%20PurchaseLine()%20%7B%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20tslint%3Adisable-next-line%3Amax-line-length%0A%20%20const%20imgUrl%20%3D%0A%20%20%20%20'https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.shopify.com%2Fs%2Ffiles%2F1%2F0938%2F8938%2Fproducts%2F10231100205_1_1315x1800_300_CMYK_1024x1024.jpeg%3Fv%3D1445623369'%3B%0A%20%20return%20(%0A%20%20%20%20%3CView%20style%3D%7Bstyles.container%7D%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CImage%20source%3D%7B%7B%20uri%3A%20imgUrl%20%7D%7D%20style%3D%7Bstyles.img%7D%20%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2FView%3E%0A%20%20)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20styles%20%3D%20StyleSheet.create(%7B%0A%20%20container%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20flex%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20%20%20backgroundColor%3A%20'red'%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20img%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20alignSelf%3A%20'center'%2C%0A%20%20%20%20width%3A%2045%2C%0A%20%20%20%20height%3A%2062%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D)%3B%0A%0Aexport%20default%20class%20Datakasse%20extends%20React.Component%3Cobject%2C%20object%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20render()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20(%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CView%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CPurchaseLine%20%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FView%3E%0A%20%20%20%20)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0AAppRegistry.registerComponent('Datakasse'%2C%20()%20%3D%3E%20Datakasse)%3B%0A)

UPDATE:

Try this example by setting flex on the parent element and remove from child. Your parent element wasnt defined as flex component so the child had issues. Check [here](https://dabbott.github.io/react-native-web-player/#code=%2F**%0A%20*%20Sample%20React%20Native%20App%0A%20*%20https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Ffacebook%2Freact-native%0A%20*%20%40flow%0A%20*%2F%0A%0Aimport%20*%20as%20React%20from%20'react'%3B%0Aimport%20%7B%20AppRegistry%2C%20View%2C%20Image%2C%20Text%2C%20StyleSheet%20%7D%20from%20'react-native'%3B%0A%0Aimport%20SplitView%20from%20'.%2Fcomponents%2FSplitView'%3B%0A%0Afunction%20PurchaseLine()%20%7B%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20tslint%3Adisable-next-line%3Amax-line-length%0A%20%20const%20imgUrl%20%3D%0A%20%20%20%20'https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.shopify.com%2Fs%2Ffiles%2F1%2F0938%2F8938%2Fproducts%2F10231100205_1_1315x1800_300_CMYK_1024x1024.jpeg%3Fv%3D1445623369'%3B%0A%20%20return%20(%0A%20%20%20%20%3CView%20style%3D%7Bstyles.container%7D%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CImage%20source%3D%7B%7B%20uri%3A%20imgUrl%20%7D%7D%20style%3D%7Bstyles.img%7D%20%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2FView%3E%0A%20%20)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20styles%20%3D%20StyleSheet.create(%7B%0A%20%20container%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20backgroundColor%3A%20'red'%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20img%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20width%3A%2045%2C%0A%20%20%20%20height%3A%2062%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D)%3B%0A%0Aexport%20default%20class%20Datakasse%20extends%20React.Component%3Cobject%2C%20object%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20render()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20(%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CView%20style%3D%7B%7Bflex%3A%201%7D%7D%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CPurchaseLine%20%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FView%3E%0A%20%20%20%20)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0AAppRegistry.registerComponent('Datakasse'%2C%20()%20%3D%3E%20Datakasse)%3B%0A)

i removed the flex from container and added here

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
```

Comment: Thanks but I dont want to keep the image at that size tho.. I just want the red containing View to wrap around the image..

Comment: sorry for that! check my updated answer for center the image inside the red container, hope that works

Comment: Sorry didn't make my self clear. The image on the right in the question is what I actually want. The problem is that I get the result on the left when I run the same code in the simulator.

Comment: i think i got it now its a typical flex problem. Check my example on the latest update and let me know

Comment: Thanks, making the container 100% height, or flex: 1 seems to work, and not setting flex: 1 on PurchaseLine's container seems to work..

Confused about why I can't use flex: 1 on PurchaseLine tho.. See my updated question..

Comment: flex: 1 gives the container the ability to expand 100% for both height and weight. What you did now is to set the parent as flex 100% on h and w and the inside as regular view. Think it about like having a 100% absolute div and setting inside regular divs