# Centering component vertically in React Native and Flexbox

Tags: android, css, react-native, flexbox

I have the following React component, which has an a list of images horizontally aligned which I would like to be centered.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import List from './src/List';
var items = require('./assets/shopping.json');

import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';

export default class AwesomeProject extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={ styles.container } >
        <List
          style = { listStyles.container }
          items={items}
          align-items="center"
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    backgroundColor: '#000000',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  }
});

const listStyles = StyleSheet.create({
  container:  {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    maxHeight: '60%',
    display: 'flex',
    backgroundColor: '#FFFF00',
  }
});



AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => AwesomeProject);
```

However, the List component is not vertically aligned:

[image]

The List has a yellow background that doesn't appear in the screenshot. That shows that it's totally covered by the image and the text. However, these are not centered vertically.

I searched in different places online, such as [here](https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/) and I incorporated the suggestions but still the List component is not centered.

So how can I make sure that the List component(with the text and image it contains) is centered vertically?

Comment: try setting 
    alignSelf: 'center', on the image

Comment: I put `alignSelf: 'center'` in basically all components but still there is no difference.

Comment: try to change the flexDirection to "column"

Answer (score 0):

i am just borrowing this answer from this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46422512/flexbox-view-does-not-wrap-image-in-react-native/46422751#46422751)

Be sure you are defining flex and the correct props to center the items.

Can you try this [demo](https://dabbott.github.io/react-native-web-player/#code=%2F**%0A%20*%20Sample%20React%20Native%20App%0A%20*%20https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Ffacebook%2Freact-native%0A%20*%20%40flow%0A%20*%2F%0A%0Aimport%20*%20as%20React%20from%20'react'%3B%0Aimport%20%7B%20AppRegistry%2C%20View%2C%20Image%2C%20Text%2C%20StyleSheet%20%7D%20from%20'react-native'%3B%0A%0Aimport%20SplitView%20from%20'.%2Fcomponents%2FSplitView'%3B%0A%0Afunction%20PurchaseLine()%20%7B%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20tslint%3Adisable-next-line%3Amax-line-length%0A%20%20const%20imgUrl%20%3D%0A%20%20%20%20'https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.shopify.com%2Fs%2Ffiles%2F1%2F0938%2F8938%2Fproducts%2F10231100205_1_1315x1800_300_CMYK_1024x1024.jpeg%3Fv%3D1445623369'%3B%0A%20%20return%20(%0A%20%20%20%20%3CView%20style%3D%7Bstyles.container%7D%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CImage%20source%3D%7B%7B%20uri%3A%20imgUrl%20%7D%7D%20style%3D%7Bstyles.img%7D%20%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CText%3Ehello%3C%2FText%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2FView%3E%0A%20%20)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20styles%20%3D%20StyleSheet.create(%7B%0A%20%20container%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20flex%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20%20%20backgroundColor%3A%20'red'%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20img%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20alignSelf%3A%20'center'%2C%0A%20%20%20%20width%3A%2045%2C%0A%20%20%20%20height%3A%2062%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D)%3B%0A%0Aexport%20default%20class%20Datakasse%20extends%20React.Component%3Cobject%2C%20object%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20render()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20(%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CView%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CPurchaseLine%20%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FView%3E%0A%20%20%20%20)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0AAppRegistry.registerComponent('Datakasse'%2C%20()%20%3D%3E%20Datakasse)%3B%0A) for your example ? If its not working can you build an example online on a dabbott?