# How to set the width of TextInput to match the parent while alignItems='center' for parent?

Tags: react-native, flexbox, alignment

I have a TextInput inside a View which has alignItems='center'.
With this settings the TextInput takes the length of the text types in the TextInput.

```
    <View style={{
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    }} >
        <TextInput />
        <Text>This is React Native</Text>
    </View>
```

Screenshots are below

[image]
[image]

Whereas what I want to achieve is align the children in the center and also stretch the width of the TextInput to match the parent

Like in this Image

[image]

How do I achieve this in react native ?

Comment: get width from dimensions and then set width of text input equal to the width you get from dimensions

Comment: Isn't there a way to set this through style ?

Comment: It will be set through style

Comment: I mean isn't there any implicit way to achieve this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [100% width in React Native Flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33297367/100-width-in-react-native-flexbox)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<View
    style={{
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: "center",
    }}>
    <TextInput />
    <Text
        style={{
            alignSelf: "center",
        }}>
        This is React Native
  </Text>
</View>
```

Replace the above code with yours.

Answer (score 0):

```
Import {Dimensions} from 'react-native';

var { height, width } = Dimensions.get('window');

<TextInput style={styles.textInput}/>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  textInput:{
    width:width;
  },  })
```